# UDP packet greater than 1475 bytes (MTU size - Headersize) silently discarded and sendto return no error

Tags: networking

When send a UDP datagram larger than the MTU size, only the last fragment of the UDP datagram is putted out to the destination. The rest of fragments are silently discarded. Sendto() return the sendlength (no error). 
Envirenment:
OS: vxWorks6.8
CPU: ARM9
MTU: 1500
The vxWorks board is direct connected via ethernet cable to the Win7 PC (with wireshark).
The DF flag isn't set.

Example 1:
sendto with 1400 Bytes
wireshark shows: udp with 1400 Databytes4

Example 2:
sendto with 1800 Bytes
wireshark shows: Fragmented IP protocol (proto=udp 0x11, off=1496, id0a00) -> Data (312 bytes)

Example 3:
sendto with 4000 Bytes
wireshark shows: Fragmented IP protocol (proto=udp 0x11, off=1496, id0a00) -> Data (1016 bytes)

Example 4:
sendto with 7800 Bytes
wireshark shows: Fragmented IP protocol (proto=udp 0x11, off=1496, id0a00) -> Data (328 bytes)

I use the same test on a second vxworks board with CPU PPC and this work fine and the ip-fragmentation work properly.

Why the first fregments of the udp packet are always discarded?
Many Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a problem in the TCP stack.  Or possibly the outgoing UDP buffers are set small enough that they can only contain one Ethernet packet's worth of information at a time?  It might be worthwhile setting SO_SNDBUF to something larger and seeing if that makes any difference.

Comment: The SNDBUF is 10K. This is big enough.